# sql select from two tables. Count is much higher?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone help me explain what is going on here.

```
select COUNT(*) from X; -- returns 764
select COUNT(*) from Y; -- returns 878
select COUNT(*) from X,Y; -- returns 670792
```

Why is the count so much higher. Wouldnt the third statement just return all the lines in X and Y? I dont quite understand why the count is so much higher.

Maybe X,Y is giving me duplicate lines?

Any explanation helps. Thanks!

Comment: it returns the cross product..`764*878` in your case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify a `join` condition , the `select` query returns a catersian product of the two tables. Each row in `x` is joined with all the other rows from `y`.

Eg: if you have 2 relations a={1,2,3} b={4,5,6} then a`X`b (cartesian product) equals {(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6)}. 
The number of elements n(a`X`b) = n(a) * n(b)

Comment: WOW I did not realize that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`select COUNT() from X; -- returns 764
select COUNT() from Y; -- returns 878
select COUNT(*) from X,Y; -- returns 670792`

Will consider as 

`select COUNT(*) from X cross join Y`

So total count will be 764*878 = 670792

if you want to do the count for X and Y (assume the structure the same in X and Y ) will be 

`select count(*) from (select * from X union select * from Y) a`